# Error in for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a dataset (Hospitals in the USA and certain values like "State", "survival rate of heart attack etc.). 
Now I want to create a function

```
function(outcome, num = "best")
```

where outcome is the "survical rate of XYZ" and num is the umpteenth Hospital of every state (e.g. "survival rate heart attack" and fifth best hospital of each state regarding the survival rate)

I want to do this with a loop (I already read in the .csv file etc.)

```
datasplit <- split(data, data$State) ## split data for every state
        results <- data.frame ## create an empty data frame


        for(i in 1:54){ ##well, 54 states
                        singlestate <- unsplit(datasplit[i], 1)
                        ordered <- singlestate[order(singlestate[,outcome], singlestate[,"Hospital.Name"], na.last=NA),]
                        ordered2 <- ordered[num,c("Hospital.Name", "State")]
                        results <-  rbind(results, ordered2)
        }
```

If I run this loop I get an Error:

```
Error in rep(xi, length.out = nvar) : 
  attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'
```

I do not really get it why the code does not work. In case you are interested in the data: http://www.file-upload.net/download-11083616/outcome-of-care-measures.csv.html

Comment: `results <- data.frame` doesn't create an empty data.frame, it assigns the function `data.frame` to the variable `results`

Comment: like @CathG said, you need `results <- data.frame()` to create an empty data.frame. also, i wouldn't use a loop for this but some `*apply` function

Comment: To solve the problem @CathG showed you  and to create an empty dataframe use: data.frame(NULL)

Comment: omg, I am new to programming and even if I double check everything - 90% of my issues are "spelling mistakes". Thanks CathG and the others for triple checking. @stasg g I learned that apply and a for loop are similar computationally intensive, is this right? so you suggest apply more for clarity?

Comment: @Gnusper comparative speed of the two approaches depend on the particular situation but R is more optimised for vectorised approaches. indeed in many cases `*apply` functions are much faster than loops. besides using `sapply` or `lapply` would spare you creating an empty data.frame and then filling it in (which is definitely inefficient).